# TypeError: string indices must be integers. It always shows that TypeError: string indices must be integers. What is the problem?

Tags: python, json

TypeError: string indices must be integers. It always shows that TypeError: string indices must be integers. What is the problem?

```
IMG_DIR = 'default/*.png'
JSON = 'annotations/default.json'
```

```
Type: \<class 'dict'\>
{'info': {}, 'categories': {'label': {'labels': \[{'name': 'keypoints', 'parent': '', 'attributes': \[\]}\], 'attributes': \['occluded'\]}, 'points': {'items': \[\]}}, 'items': \[{'id': '1024_2048_eduart_420210919_151508', 'annotations': \[{'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[326.46, 438.63\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[499.41, 452.61\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[430.61, 454.51\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[37.47, 467.43\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}\], 'attr': {'frame': 0}, 'image': {'path': '1024_2048_eduart_420210919_151508.png', 'size': \[512, 512\]}, 'media': {'path': '1024_2048_eduart_420210919_151508.png'}}, {'id': '1536_1024_imranparkhaus_rub_32', 'annotations': \[{'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[234.13, 427.51\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}\], 'attr': {'frame': 1}, 'image': {'path': '1536_1024_imranparkhaus_rub_32.png', 'size': \[512, 512\]}, 'media': {'path': '1536_1024_imranparkhaus_rub_32.png'}}, {'id': '1536_1536_eduart_5642', 'annotations': \[{'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[151.31, 437.21\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}\], 'attr': {'frame': 2}, 'image': {'path': '1536_1536_eduart_5642.png', 'size': \[512, 512\]}, 'media': {'path': '1536_1536_eduart_5642.png'}}, {'id': '1536_2560_evgenii_NL_3_120200916_154505', 'annotations': \[{'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[51.14, 399.35\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[458.94, 104.43\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}\], 'attr': {'frame': 3}, 'image': {'path': '1536_2560_evgenii_NL_3_120200916_154505.png', 'size': \[512, 512\]}, 'media': {'path': '1536_2560_evgenii_NL_3_120200916_154505.png'}}, {'id': '2048_1024_imran20200801_171936', 'annotations': \[{'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[298.43, 411.32\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}\], 'attr': {'frame': 4}, 'image': {'path': '2048_1024_imran20200801_171936.png', 'size': \[512, 512\]}, 'media': {'path': '2048_1024_imran20200801_171936.png'}}, {'id': '2048_1024_imran20200801_184730', 'annotations': \[{'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[480.6, 451.42\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}\], 'attr': {'frame': 5}, 'image': {'path': '2048_1024_imran20200801_184730.png', 'size': \[512, 512\]}, 'media': {'path': '2048_1024_imran20200801_184730.png'}}, {'id': '2048_1536_imran20200801_171936', 'annotations': \[{'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[4.51, 353.86\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[320.5, 270.6\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[395.73, 240.58\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[169.28, 344.01\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}\], 'attr': {'frame': 6}, 'image': {'path': '2048_1536_imran20200801_171936.png', 'size': \[512, 512\]}, 'media': {'path': '2048_1536_imran20200801_171936.png'}}, {'id': '512_1024_eduart_420210722_170544', 'annotations': \[{'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[506.42, 188.26\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[195.07, 50.01\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[68.4, 42.31\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[176.4, 222.6\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[349.96, 240.88\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}\], 'attr': {'frame': 7}, 'image': {'path': '512_1024_eduart_420210722_170544.png', 'size': \[512, 512\]}, 'media': {'path': '512_1024_eduart_420210722_170544.png'}}, {'id': '512_1024_eduart_5493', 'annotations': \[\], 'attr': {'frame': 8}, 'image': {'path': '512_1024_eduart_5493.png', 'size': \[512, 512\]}, 'media': {'path': '512_1024_eduart_5493.png'}}, {'id': '512_1024_eduart_5840', 'annotations': \[{'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[360.2, 476.5\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[355.6, 404.8\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[410.1, 121.3\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}\], 'attr': {'frame': 9}, 'image': {'path': '512_1024_eduart_5840.png', 'size': \[512, 512\]}, 'media': {'path': '512_1024_eduart_5840.png'}}, {'id': '512_2048_eduart_5702', 'annotations': \[{'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[336.33, 51.5\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[201.1, 421.4\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[271.4, 115.9\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}\], 'attr': {'frame': 10}, 'image': {'path': '512_2048_eduart_5702.png', 'size': \[512, 512\]}, 'media': {'path': '512_2048_eduart_5702.png'}}, {'id': '512_2560_eduart_5extra_35', 'annotations': \[{'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[494.65, 24.64\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[349.52, 295.38\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}\], 'attr': {'frame': 11}, 'image': {'path': '512_2560_eduart_5extra_35.png', 'size': \[512, 512\]}, 'media': {'path': '512_2560_eduart_5extra_35.png'}}, {'id': '512_2560_evgenii_Ext_120201005_142724', 'annotations': \[{'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[434.69, 169.45\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}, {'id': 0, 'type': 'points', 'attributes': {'occluded': False}, 'group': 0, 'label_id': 0, 'points': \[392.64, 212.4\], 'z_order': 0, 'visibility': \[2\]}\], 'attr': {'frame': 12}, 'image': {'path': '512_2560_evgenii_Ext_120201005_142724.png', 'size': \[512, 512\]}, 'media': {'path': '512_2560_evgenii_Ext_120201005_142724.png'}}, {'id': '512_512_imran20200801_170919', 'annotations': \[\], 'attr': {'frame': 13}, 'image': {'path': '512_512_imran20200801_170919.png', 'size': \[512, 512\]}, 'media': {'path': '512_512_imran20200801_170919.png'}}\]}
```

```
with open(JSON) as infile:
json_data = json.load(infile)
json_dict = {i\['path'\]: i for i in json_data}
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3884/156696908.py in <module>
      1 with open(JSON) as infile:
      2     json_data = json.load(infile)
----> 3 json_dict = {i['path']: i for i in json_data}

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_3884/156696908.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
      1 with open(JSON) as infile:
      2     json_data = json.load(infile)
----> 3 json_dict = {i['path']: i for i in json_data}

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: should it be `json_dict = {json_data[i]['path']: i for i in json_data}`

Comment: But it gives me KeyError: 'path'

Comment: traceback is pointing you in right direction, read it TypeError carefully again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems that you are looking for `path` for your each value. So you need to be aware of your data frame. Because where your `path` is located is in your `items` only. That's why you are facing above error. Please the following code where your `path`s are collected.

```
json_dict = {}

for k,v in json_data.items():
    if k == "items":
        for i in v:
            for k1,v1 in i.items():
                if type(v1) == dict: # Seems, the "path" only includes in a dict {'path': '2048_1024_imran20200801_184730.png', 'size': [512, 512]}
                    for k11,v11 in v1.items():
                        if k11 == "path":
                            json_dict[f"{i['id']}--{k1}-path"] = v11
```

See code output below, you may edit your the key values as you wish by editing json_dict.

[image]

Comment: but it gives me AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: can you edit `JSON.items()` as `json_data.items()` and try again? I have edited my answer as well.

Comment: no output came.

Comment: Well, it does work for me. You are printing `print(json_dict)` right?